# Container (Apache) exit after 1 seconds

Tags: docker, containers, start

I've made a mistake in my apache2.conf and so every time I try to start the container, it exits:

```
#docker start portail
portail
#docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                  NAMES
0c2cd80ab3fc        jnyryan/simplesamlphp   "/usr/sbin/apache2ct   25 hours ago        Exited (1) 1 seconds ago                                                          portail
```

So how can I resolve my problem? I've made many changes in the container and I don't want to lose it.

Do I need to change the start command of the container? If so, how?

Comment: Do you really think whatever you provide is enough for someone to help you?

Comment: Yeah normally it's very clear if you had already worked in docker. The question is: How to change the start command so you could rectify your config?

Comment: don't change start command, just update your config file and then start apache/container

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking of. So write a well written answer so I can give you points.

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, problem is with `apache2.conf` and not with docker, so address your issue with `apache2.conf` and restart your container.

*** UPDATE ***

you should update your docker package to latest version ([Installation on CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/))

```
$ rpm -q docker
docker-1.9.1-25.el7.centos.x86_64
$
```

then use [cp](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy working `apache2.conf`.

Comment: How? Can you be more specific. The server apache is the container that doesn't start.

Comment: start from undo your last changes to `apache2.conf`

Comment: Yeah let's say that I have a working apache2.conf. Now how can I pass it to my container? I'm using docker 1.7 in CentOS

Comment: How can I update my docker, I can't get a tutorial working with a version greater than 1.71